# Approve Page Edits

Tags: pages

I'd like to create a role group where users can edit pages and submit them for approval before they are displayed on the website. I've used the following roles (shown below) but they don't allow me to approve page edits. Is it possible to create a role where a user can edit pages and then have the edits be approved by me before  being shown on the website?

```
edit_pages
edit_published_pages
edit_others_pages
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used the revisionary plugin and it was able to do what I needed. The plugin can be found [here](http://wordpress.org/plugins/revisionary/)

Answer (score 0):

This is something you could accomplish with the [Groups](http://wordpress.org/plugins/groups/) plugin. You could assign those capabilities to your authors within the defined group and only you would have the `publish_posts`capability.

Comment: I'm a little confused with the plugin. Does the plugin offer anything more than the standard WordPress capabilities?
http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities

Comment: You would create a new group and assign your authors to it with these permissions: edit_pages, edit_published_pages, edit_others_pages. Then they should only be able to save the pages as drafts.

Comment: Sorry Jordan, thinking this through more. I'm not sure of a way for an author to edit a live page while keeping the previous version published until approval. The method I've described here would unpublish the page.

Comment: That's a shame. I appreciate your help.